# DataFrame object is not callable. Yfinance

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, yfinance

```
class SAnalysis:

def __init__(self, scrip):
    self.scrip = scrip
    self.data = yf.Ticker(self.scrip)

def get_history(self):
    data = self.data.history()
    return data

def get_balance_sheet(self, limit = '1y'):
    b_sheet = self.data.balance_sheet(period =  limit)
    return b_sheet



s = SAnalysis('NVDA')

s.get_history().head()
```

This part of the code works just fine and returns stuff like it should.

```
s.get_balance_sheet('2y')
```

This part doesn't. Brings up this error on running

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[18], line 1
----> 1 s.get_balance_sheet('2y')

 Cell In[13], line 12, in SAnalysis.get_balance_sheet(self, limit)
 11 def get_balance_sheet(self, limit = '1y'):
 ---> 12     b_sheet = self.data.balance_sheet(period =  limit)
 13     return b_sheet

TypeError: 'DataFrame' object is not callable
```

Comment: Hi Shimron, check out the docs for a [DataFrame](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.html), it's not called like a function using parenthesis.

Comment: What exactly is the `limit` argument in the `get_balance_sheet` function supposed to do?

Comment: it is supposed to get you the data from today to the limit time. For instance, if you give in '3y', it'll or at least it is supposed to get you the most recent 3years' data

Comment: @ShimronAlakkal So for `3y` it should give you dataframe with 3 most recent columns?

Answer (score 1):

Based on the description, I assume self.data.balance_sheet is a DataFrame. So the error comes when you try to call it here, since a DataFram is not callable:

```
b_sheet = self.data.balance_sheet(period =  limit)
```

Just filter the data in the DataFrame based on your argumet, dont call it!

Comment: This would work and it did, but, what if the user wants to get the data for a set number of years.

Comment: What do you mean by a set? If you want between a range you can use something like self.data.balance_sheet[(self.data["Year"] >= start_year) & (self.data["Year"] <= end_year)].

Answer (score 0):

The error was gone when I removed the parameter part of the method call.

```
b_sheet = self.data.balance_sheet
```

Although the code seems to work with the parameters, outside of a class, perfectly, when it is called inside a method in a class it can't take params.

```
b_sheet = data.balance_sheet(period =  limit)
```

The above part works just fine as it is not inside a class and is called outside. Kinda in a global scope.